# Product of sines to sum

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, sequences-and-series, quantum-mechanics

I hope this is a research level question; it is to me at least, I'm a beginning researcher in the field of the Bethe Ansatz. In the expressions I'm considering, I stumbled across the following identity in my system:
\begin{align}
\prod_{j=1}^N \sin a_j
\end{align}
which I need to rewrite as (for example) a sum of sines or other expressions. The $a_j$ in my context must be treated as completely general real variables, but with distinct numerical values, and $N$ some positive, large integer. At a certain point I am required to take a sum over $p$ when $a_j\mapsto pb_j+c_j$. If the expressions that arise remain simple that would be a tremendous plus. It is fine if we get products of rational functions, as these can be simplified using Heaviside's decomposition.

So I know of the double angle formula, which yes, in principle allows for rewriting this expression as a sum:
\begin{align}
\prod_{j=1}^N \sin a_j &= \frac1{2^{N-1}} \sum_{\sigma_2,\cdots,\sigma_N=\pm} \left[\prod_{j=2}^N \sigma_j\right]\sin\left[a_1 + \sum_{j=2}^N \sigma_j a_j + \frac{\pi(1-N)}2\right]
\end{align}
however it is not clear what the meaning is (in the analytical sense) of the resulting expressions. In my system $N$ will get very large, and it is not clear how to proceed with the expressions that follow. (What is an infinite-fold signed sum of sines?! No idea either.)

A potential option would be to proceed with the expression and use the following result of the binomial theorem in reverse:
\begin{align}
\prod_{j=1}^N f_j &= \frac1{2^{N-1}N!}\sum_{\sigma_{2,\dots,N} = \pm} \left(\prod_{j=2}^N \sigma_j \right) \left(f_1+\sum_{i=2}^N \sigma_j f_j\right)^N
\end{align}

This would require us to find a function $f$ that satisfies it.

Second option is to indeed use the above identity with the subset of symmetric summations over the substitution alluded to earlier. In my system I can choose to be sloppy with regards to winding numbers and the likes, so I can expand the complex exponent without any additional factors. Suppose also $n$ is a positive integer, then we would get
\begin{align}
\sum_{p=-n}^n \prod_{j=1}^N \sin (pb_j+c_j) &= \frac1{2^{N-1}} \sum_{\sigma_2,\cdots,\sigma_N=\pm} \left[\prod_{j=2}^N \sigma_j\right] \sum_{p=-n}^n\sin\left[pb_j+c_j + p\sum_{k=2}^N \sigma_k b_k + \sum_{k=2}^N \sigma_k c_k + \frac{\pi(1-N)}2\right]\\
&= \frac1{i2^{N}} \sum_{\sigma_2,\cdots,\sigma_N=\pm} \left[\prod_{j=2}^N \sigma_j\right] \left[\exp\left[ic_j + i\sum_{k=2}^N \sigma_k c_k + \frac{i\pi(1-N)}2 \right] \left(\sum_{p=-n}^n \exp\left[ipb_j + ip\sum_{k=2}^N \sigma_k b_k\right]\right) - \exp\left[-ic_j - i\sum_{k=2}^N \sigma_k c_k + \frac{i\pi(N-1)}2 \right] \left(\sum_{p=-n}^n \exp\left[-ipb_j - ip\sum_{k=2}^N \sigma_k b_k\right]\right)\right]
\end{align}
then using that the resulting Dirichlet kernel is an even function, to perhaps extract it using a finite size Cauchy product identity.

I hope somebody here in MO can offer some insight.

Comment: If I remember correctly my 8-grade math, $\sin x \sin y = 1/2(\cos (x-y)-\cos(x+y))$ and $\sin x \cos y = 1/2(\sin (x + y) +\sin(x-y)$),

Comment: @MarkSapir Indeed, though any cosine can be rewritten as a translated sine, hence the expression above. Your expression and mine are identical.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: The question is how I can sum over large products of sines, say $\sum_{p=1}^5 \prod_j \sin(a_jp^2+b_jp+c_j)$. The sin can be expanded with my rule above, but then what?

Comment: Replace each product as a sum. Then you will have a large sum.